# How to restyle or remove button (focused) inner border

Tags: html, css, button, border, internet-explorer-11

In the picture below, you can see that there is a dashed "inner" border around the ">" symbol, indicating that the button is focused. (I have also added a blue border around the button)

In my code where I am constructing these buttons I am doing:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  nextBtn.focus();
}, 100);
```

My current CSS is:

```
.TutorialBtn {
  border: none;
}

.TutorialBtn:hover:enabled {
  background: #5BE3F5;
}

.TutorialBtn:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

My question is simply: How can I remove or restyle this inner border?

[image]

Comment: Could you share an url where we could see the code live?

Comment: @FlorinPop No, I can't

Comment: @ControlAltDel Have you tried with outline property? Like outline: none;

Comment: @DiegoRosales solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input[type="submit"]:focus{outline:none}
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner{border:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the outline property:

```
outline: none;
```

Ref. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp